Unsubstantiated assumption in a problem about two particles rotating around each other
In solving the following problem from Kleppner and Kolenkow

the solution assumes there is a point $C$ along the line joining $m$ and $M$ such that

Both $m$ and $M$ execute uniform circular motion with the same angular velocity $\omega$ about $C$

$C$ is inertial and thus $F=mr\omega^2=M(R-r)\omega^2$ applies


I don't understand how those two statements follow from the fact that each particle executes UCM about the other with angular velocity $\omega$.
The fact that there exists a point $C$ (namely, the center of mass) along the line joining the masses that is inertial does follow from conservation of linear momentum, but this problem is presented before the introduction of the concept of momentum, so I think there should be a way to do it without this. Moreover, I still can't deduce (1) from it.
Any hint would be appreciated.

You can use kinematics of circular motion to solve this.
As the bodies perform uniform circular motion about each other, it means that with respect to one of the bodies, the velocity of other body is perpendicular (condition for circular motion). As the circular motion is uniform, there is not tangential acceleration, which means the Force must be in the along the line joining the two masses(lets call the line joining the masses "AB"). As force is constant and always perpendicular to the masses' velocity, we can observe from the ground frame and say that each mass is doing uniform circular motion about a fixed point(or intertial) lying on the line joining the two masses. (As magnitude of force is constant and always perpendicular to velocity)
Now here's the tricky part, which is proving that the two centers of these moving masses are at the same point. Assume that the centers do not coincide. If they do not coincide, then the distance between the masses will continuously change, but the distance between the bodies is constant, thus, the centers coincide. Therefore we proved that the bodies perform uniform circular motion about a fixed common point on the line AB.
There is another method which is of center of mass.
F=$\frac{dp}{dt}$. Take both bodies as a system. There is no external force, so the Center of mass of the system remains at rest, therefore directly proving that the system rotates about the COM.

"As the circular motion is uniform, there is not tangential acceleration, which means the Force must be in the along the line joining the two masses". No tangential acceleration does not imply no tangential force when observing from a non-inertial frame of reference, and the frame attached to each particle (assuming both rotate about their center of mass) is certainly non-inertial, so I think this reasoning is fallacious

Since the body rotates about a fixed point, its speed is constant, but you are correct, the frame is not inertial. The acceleration of the bodies will be towards each other from a inertial frame, like the Earth. From a non intertial frame, there will be a pseudo force opposite to the direction of frame's acceleration. This means the pseudo force away from the other body. Therefore there is no component of force in tangential direction. Also if there was a net component of force in the tangential direction, there would certainly be tangential acceleration with respect to the non intertial frame

"From a non intertial frame, there will be a pseudo force opposite to the direction of frame's acceleration. This means the pseudo force away from the other body." To make this claim, you use the fact that each body is executing UCM when observed from an inertial frame which is what was to be deduced in the first place, rendering your reasoning circular

I deduced that they were UCM, by the fact that they are in UCM with respect to each other. This piece of information was given in the question.

How does being in UCM with respect to each other imply UCM with respect to an inertial frame?

Its explained in the answer. For the distance between them to be constant, and for the angular velocity to be also constant, the force is perpendicular to the line joining AB, thus proving UCM for each individual particle

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
